# Shortcut for empty with collider

Tags: unity

How to add shortcut key to add new empty already with a box/circle collider ?

If possible, it would be nice that empties are enumerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a script and specify the shortcuts with the [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) attribute :

> To create a hotkey you can use the following special characters: % (ctrl on Windows, cmd on macOS), # (shift), & (alt). A hotkey text must be preceded with a space character ("MyMenu/Do_g" won't be interpreted as hotkey, while "MyMenu/Do _g" will).

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
public class MenuTest : MonoBehaviour {

    [MenuItem ("MyMenu/Create Box Collider %#x")]
    static void CreateBoxCollider () {
        GameObject g = new GameObject("Box Collider") ;
        g.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    [MenuItem ("MyMenu/Create Sphere Collider %#h")]
    static void CreateSphereCollider () {
        GameObject g = new GameObject("Sphere Collider") ;
        g.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
    }

    [MenuItem ("MyMenu/Create Capsule Collider %#c")]
    static void CreateCapsuleCollider () {
        GameObject g = new GameObject("Capsule Collider") ;
        g.AddComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    }
}
```

Be careful to not use a shortcut already used by Unity itself.

**Important note** : Since it's an editor script. You must place it in a folder named "Editor" at the root of your project

Comment: Where to apply this script? On camera ?                              **Assets/MenuTest.cs(18,38): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `Capsule Collider'**

Comment: Not necessarily, just create a new CS file named "MenuTest" and copy-paste this code. You don't even have to put the script on a gameobject ! Sorry for the `CS1525` error. I fixed the script in my answer

Comment: Question about capsule collider. Does **%#c** mean **CTRL+C** ? Because this is for copying.

Comment: %#c means CTRL + SHIFT + C
Feel free to change the shortcuts, it was just an example to show you how to do ;)

Comment: Great. Thanks, this works! Is it possible to make enumeration of Gameobjects created?

Comment: What do you mean by "enumerated" ? With a number at the end of the name for example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54074/discussion-between-dan-monsic-and-hellium).